# working with electron-edge-js for existing dll with app.config

Tags: electron, edgejs

Using electron-edge-js calling a c# dll method, But its not reading config data from node.exe.config file. Is there any other do we need to keep app.config for electron?

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by renaming the node.exe.config to myapp.exe.config