# Electron-Edge-JS App.config

Tags: c#, node.js, electron, app-config, edgejs

I am using electron-edge-js to call a C# DLL.

Within the DLL, the App.config file is called out for server connection information.

```
return (ServiceDetailConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(ServiceDetailConfiguration.ServiceDetailConfigurationConst);
```

In my js file calling the dll, I can successfully call out to the dll, and process information. That is, until I hit the above line, I get a null exception thrown as it can't find the app.config.

I've tried the below:

[Load WCF app.config bindings in edge.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170174/load-wcf-app-config-bindings-in-edge-js-app)

[working with electron-edge-js for existing dll with app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851544/working-with-electron-edge-js-for-existing-dll-with-app-config)

Without much luck.

In my package.json file, the name is "firstelectronapp".
When i build the file, I output it as "test.exe"

So i've attempted these files in the same root folder as the test.exe file with no luck:

- first.exe.config
- firstelectronapp.exe.config
- test.exe.config
- node.exe.config

Is there something I'm missing? I wrote a quick C# app with an app.config that calls the dll, and when stepping through it I can tell that's what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file should be renamed electron.exe.config and placed in the same directory as electron.exe - i.e. `node_modules\electron\dist`.

I just ran into this when needing to add a bindingRedirect. Putting it in the above file solved it.

Also, if you're using electron-builder for packaging the app, you can easily include the config file in the packaged application by adding it to the extraFiles collection in the build configuration, for instance:

```
"extraFiles": [
  {
    "from": "app.config",
    "to": "my-electron-app-name.exe.config"
  }
]
```